# Bash - Mistake of Bubble sort for arguments

Tags: bash, sorting, bubble-sort

Have to sort arguments using Bubble Sort.

```
#!/bin/bash

myArray=( "$@" )

for((i = 0; i<${#myArray[@]}; i++))
do
    
    for((j = i; j<${#myArray[@]}-i-1; j++))
    do
    
        if [[ ${myArray[j]} > ${myArray[$((j+1))]} ]]
        then
            temp=${myArray[j]}
            myArray[$j]=${myArray[$((j+1))]}  
            myArray[$((j+1))]=$temp
        fi
    done
done

for i in ${myArray[@]}; do
    echo $i;
done
```

Tried to input d c b a. Output: a b c d. Tried to input a b c d. Output: c a b d.
Where is mistake?

Comment: Good job on providing code along with test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd loop should start at 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

myArray=( "$@" )
for((i=0; i<${#myArray[@]}; i++))
do
    for((j=0; j<${#myArray[@]}-i-1; j++))
    do
        if [[ ${myArray[j]} > ${myArray[$((j+1))]} ]]
        then
            temp=${myArray[j]}
            myArray[$j]=${myArray[$((j+1))]}  
            myArray[$((j+1))]=$temp
        fi
    done
done

for i in ${myArray[@]}; do
    echo $i;
done
```